# Excel VLOOKUP to return blank if no values detected

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this column A with VLOOKUP formula and if VLOOKUP formula detects blank in cells to return blank, right now if VLOOKUP detects blank it will return - since the cells in column are marked as "Accounting cells".

```
|  Column A  |                                 |  Column B  |
| € 1.287,00 |                                 | € 1.287,00 | 
| € 3.519,60 |                                 | € 3.519,60 |
| €    0     |                                 | €    0     |
| €  475,00  |    And I want to get this -->   | €  475,00  |
| €    -     |                                 |            |
| €    -     |                                 |            |
| €    -     |                                 |            |
```

I have tried adding IFERROR and IFNA but nothing worked.

Comment: You could do this : `=LET(α,VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index,0),IF(α=0,"",α))` or if you don't have access to `LET()` then `IF(VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index,0)=0,"",VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index,0))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya the 2nd formula is working

Comment: Oh okay let me post the same as an answer then. Also the second one is working for you because you may not be using ms365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above try one of the following based on your Excel Version.

---

For MS365 Users

```
=LET(α,VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index,0),IF(α=0,"",α))
```

---

For Non-MS365 Users

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index,0)=0,"",VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index,0))
```

---